# VBA Delete Sheets Based of A1 Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is for deleting each tab that says Delete in cell A1.

What I don’t understand is that in one workbook it works and the next workbook it give me Run-Time error 13 type mismatch.

Please let me know if you see why I am receiving Run-time error 13.

```vb
Sub DeleteTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- `Sheets` collection that represents all the sheets ( include worksheet and chart sheet )
- `Dim ws As Worksheet`, ie. `ws` is defined as worksheet object. `For` loop interation raises error 13 if there is a chart sheet in the workbook.

If you want to delete chart sheet too,

```
Sub DeleteTabs()
    Dim ws As Object
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If TypeName(ws) = "Chart" Then
            ws.Delete ' modify as needed
        Else
            If ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
                ws.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

OR, you only care about worksheet.

```
Sub DeleteTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Workbook.Sheets property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheets?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm199152)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

**Note**: Please refer to @VBasic2008's reply if you want to have a more reliable way to compare cell value.

Comment: There is no `Sheet` object. To distinguish between sheets and worksheets, I prefer to use the `sh` variable for sheets so you would do `Dim sh As Object`. When you loop over the elements of a collection using a `For Each...Next` loop, once you delete an item, the previously next item becomes the current item and is skipped in the next iteration. If the cell contains an error value, the comparison will raise error 13.

Comment: You are right, it should be `Object`. Thx. Base on my testing with Excel 365, using a `For Each...Next` loop to delete sheet doesn't have any issue. No skipping.

Comment: You are right about the `For Each...Next` loop. I need to get my head examined. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Worksheets Containing a String in a Cell

```vb
Sub DeleteWorksheets()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Worksheets"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, w As Long, ErrorNumber As Long, Msg As String
    
    For w = wsCount To 1 Step -1
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(w)
        If StrComp(CStr(ws.Range("A1").Value), "Delete", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                On Error Resume Next
                    ws.Delete
                    ErrorNumber = Err.Number
                On Error GoTo 0
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            If ErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Msg = Msg & vbLf & vbTab & ws.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next w

    If Len(Msg) > 0 Then
        Msg = "The following worksheet(s) could not be deleted:" & vbLf & Msg
        MsgBox Msg, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox "All worksheets deleted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
        
End Sub
```